# CSS grid doesn't fill up the remaining space

Tags: html, css, css-grid

In my `Angular` project, I have a `paragraph`, an `image`, and a `button`.

I'm using `css grid` to make them look like the design but no matter how hard I try, they don't take up the remaining height.

As you can see in the images below, the button should be at the very bottom.

Below is the design I'm trying to achieve:

[image: Design file]

And this is what I have:

[image]

My `html` code:

```
<div id="parent-container">
        <img id="image" src="assets/images/kyc-newbie.svg" alt="newbie"/>
        <p id="description" class="settings-page__info">
          As a user, you must verify your identity in order to make transactions on Didex platforms
        </p>
        <a id="button" routerLink="/user/kyc">
          <button mat-raised-button color="primary">
            Verify Identity
          </button>
         </a>
</div>
```

And here's the `scss`:

```
#parent-container {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-rows: repeat(8, auto);
      grid-template-columns: 100%;
      row-gap: 40px;
      grid-template-areas:
        '.'
        '.'
        '.'
        'image'
        'description'
        '.'
        '.'
        'button';
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      max-height: 100vh;

      #image {
        grid-area: image;
      }
      #description {
        grid-area: description;
      }
      #button {
        grid-area: button;
      }
}
```

Comment: The `<a>` link is the grid item, not the `<button>`. Can the `<button>` element be removed and material button styles be applied to the `<a>` element?

Comment: Links cannot contain buttons and vice versa. It's invalid HTML

Comment: @stealththeninja I removed the `a` tag and added the `routerlink` to `button` tag. It's working fine now but it still doesn't span the whole height of the container.

Comment: @Paulie_D thank you for mentioning that. I removed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your element is not spanning the whole viewport.

You can set the height of the  `#parent-container`
to take up the whole viewport by giving it `min-height: 100vh`.

edit: Or just give it a height value of 100vh instead of 100%: `height: 100vh`.

Comment: I tried both `height` and `min-height` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Looking back at your CSS, you are missing the closing bracket for  #parent-container, so the style declarations below it are not being applied.

Comment: thank you for mentioning that. I fixed that and it still doesn't work.

Comment: That together with setting the height/min-height should be enough. I've added your code to a codepen to illustrate: https://codepen.io/stevenkuipers/pen/GRoLJoO